# How to edit Layout to full length of screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i have an app which has a main RelativeLayout and some LinearLayout within it.
My problem is that the LinearLayout doesn't fit to the full lenght of the screen:
this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/bgApp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/topBarHeight"
            android:background="@drawable/top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scoreLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/coin_icon" 
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainScreenTotalPoints"
                    style="@style/pointTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/btnPaddingV"
                    android:text="@string/startPoint"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/buttonTextSize" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/logPadding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#d0105e"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/btnPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/btnPadding" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onButtonClickPlay"
                android:text="@string/play"
                android:textColor="@color/btnMain"
                android:textSize="@dimen/buttonTextSize" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/mainbox" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btnPadding" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_how"
                        style="@style/btnCapital"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnPaddingV"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_green_how"
                        android:onClick="onButtonClickHowToPlay"
                        android:text="@string/howInfo" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_rate"
                        style="@style/btnCapital"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/btnPaddingV"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_rate"
                        android:onClick="onButtonClickRate"
                        android:text="@string/rateInfo" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btnPadding" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/sound"
                        style="@style/btnCapital"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@drawable/mute_01"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="onButtonClickSound"
                        android:text="@string/mute" />


                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btnPadding" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/moreapp"
                        style="@style/btnCapital"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="onButtonClickMoreApp"
                        android:text="@string/moreapp" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

here is a screenshot :
[Screenshot after running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bycCV.png)

and here a screenshot of layout before running app:
[Screenshot before running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnZtm.png)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ScrollView attribute called `android:fillViewport="true"`. This attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed.

When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect.

Check out [this](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) for detail explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment .. you're right it had no effect, but may be i didn't put the attribute at the right place !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use attribute  android:fillViewport="true".in your scrollview.

Comment: @Youness, have you try this?

Comment: yes i have tried this but no effect .. may be i didn't add this attribute in the right place ! :/

Comment: i have added it on yje firls lines, like that :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/bgApp" >